# How to create a custom frame with win32

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, win32gui

I want to create a container control that has an optional border that can be programmatically set as to color and thickness.  I also require rounded corners and it must be done in C++ win32 only - no MFC, ATL, winforms etc.  The purpose of the control is solely to contain other controls.

I've done a lot of reading and experimenting but haven't found any tutorial that exactly demonstrates what I'm trying to do.  The following code comes closest but fails because the button encroaches on the border instead of being clipped.  How to clip child controls so they don't paint over the border?

The following is the complete minimalist version that runs on VS2015

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Resource.h"
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcPanel(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInst, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInst, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = {};

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("main");
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create main window.
    HWND MWhwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, _T("main"), _T(""), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcPanel;
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("CPanel");
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create container panel
    HWND Panelhwnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, _T("CPanel"), _T(""), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, 100, 20, 110, 100, MWhwnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    // Add Button to container panel
    CreateWindowEx(NULL, WC_BUTTON, _T("OK"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 50, 24, Panelhwnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);

    ShowWindow(MWhwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcPanel(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_NCPAINT:  // here I'm creating the border
            {
                RECT rect;
                GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
                OffsetRect(&rect, -rect.left, -rect.top);
                HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hwnd);

                HRGN g_hrgnButton = CreateRoundRectRgn(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 40, 40);
                FrameRgn(hdc, g_hrgnButton, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(50, 50, 255)), 5, 5);

                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
                return 0;
            }
        case WM_NCCALCSIZE:  // here I think I'm setting the client area size.
            {
                RECT *rc = (RECT*)lParam;
                InflateRect(rc, -5, -5);
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:  // Setting the client area background color
            {
                PAINTSTRUCT ps;
                HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

                RECT rect = ps.rcPaint;
                HRGN hrgn = CreateRoundRectRgn(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 40, 40);
                SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
                SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
                PaintRgn(hdc, hrgn);

                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
        }    
     return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see, the top left corner border is covered by the button.

Comment: Probably not related, but you've not quite implemented WM_NCCALCSIZE properly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Were you expecting the button to be clipped by the rounded rectangle?

Comment: The blue border should paint over or clip the button.  The green area is supposed to be the client area and the blue the non-client.  I've tried numerous approaches but I'm out of my depth and out of ideas.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe that is correct, actually

Comment: @poby you are not handling WM_NCCALCSIZE correctly. Read [these](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030911-00/?p=42553) [posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030915-00/?p=42493) if MSDN confuses you.

Comment: @andlabs: Even if you did handle `WM_NCCALCSIZE` properly, how would you report a non-rectangular client region?

Comment: @IInspectable of course; the client region would have to be the largest rectangle within that rounded rectangle. The alternative would be to make the client area everything and manually track what the "real" client rect is, possibly with a custom shape for the button too. The latter is what you have to do if you extend the DWM frame into the client area, so...

Comment: @andlabs: When/how do you set up clipping then? If you cannot specify a non-rectangular client region, the system isn't going to do it for you. This is what the OP is having difficulty with, and properly handling `WM_NCCALCSIZE` isn't going to solve that issue.

Comment: @IInspectable with the second option? You would have to manually ensure your children never cross into the fake nonclient area; I wouldn't know if you could clip children yourself.... I'm not sure what appearance the OP wants to go for...

Comment: I thought there might be an easy fix I was missing but it seems not.  The only idea I can think of atm, is to create a borderless window within a borderless window, use the inner window as the "client area" and use `SetWindowRgn` to ensure anything that extends outside the window boundary gets clipped. The outer window will act as the border.  I think this might work visually but this seems a horrible hack.

Comment: @poby it would help if you showed us a mockup of the UI you want. Can you?

Comment: @andlabs No I can't really as I haven't fully designed it yet.  But I need control containers and I want them to have round corners (like in the pic shown above).  I'm thinking now I will either go with a window in a window approach or else stick with a square client area that fully fits within the round cornered border. Leaning towards the latter though the NC area becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: @poby well you'll still need to decide how much of the green part of your image you want to be available to controls. Using only what Windows gives you, you'll need to choose a strict rectangle out of that green. If you want to use the entire green area, you'll have to do all the work yourself, including making everything positioned nicely, and that depends on your eventual UI design...